# Xamarin Android UITest StartApp AppDataMode.DoNotClear ignored

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to write UiTests for a Xamarin Android App that initially downloads a lot of data. Everytime I start a new test, the app data is cleared completely and I have to wait a rather long time to test again.

My `BeforeEachTest()` looks like this:

```
app = ConfigureApp.Android
                .ApkFile("pathToAPK")
                .StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```

It seems that it is being ignored, and between each test, I do not change the source code of my app at all (or I'm not aware of it).

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround.
Instead of StartApp() i used ConnectToApp().
My tests now run on an manually opened instance of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
                IApp IApp = ConfigureApp
                .Android.ApkFile(apkPath)
                .EnableLocalScreenshots()
                .LogDirectory(logDirectory)
                .DeviceSerial("DeviceToBeSelect")
                .StartApp();
```